# mongoose cannot save subdocument array after findOne

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to do something like this:

```
Industry.findOne({_id: id}).exec(function(err, industry){

    industry.stats = _.extend(industry.stats, stats);    //.......(1)

    industry.save(function(err) {
         // nothing is saved
    });
});
```

The console.log of industry.stats in (1) is

```
[{ stat_id: 545080c8e4e88b1d5a7a6d1b}{ stat_id: 54526ca6b294096d33ca6b36 }]
```

This is not working, apparently the industry.stats is not an object array and misses a comma in between the two objects.  (am I stating this correctly?)

If I assign industry.stats directly like this

```
[{stat_id: 545080c8e4e88b1d5a7a6d1b}, {stat_id: 54526ca6b294096d33ca6b36}]
```

Then it's working.  Is there something I need to do to convert (1) to an object array first?  I tried lean() and toObject()...etc but I got no luck.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Lodash `extend` will assign own enumerable properties of source object to the destination object. In this case array properties of the source (`stats`) are copied to `industry.stats`.  This will not work for arrays.

You'll have to update the array via array functions (`push`, `pull`,...) or set the field directly.